# Codeigniter Data Table SQL Query Issue

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables-1.10

I have a program to manage the balance qty vs issued fuels to some of vehicles

In simplest, thats include the following tables

## store_item

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| item_id | item_name | status |
+---------+-----------+--------+
|       1 | Diesel    |      1 |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

## tbl_vehicle

```
+------------+------------+
| vehicle_id | vehicle_no |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |       4545 |
|          2 |       4546 |
|          3 |       4547 |
|         18 |       4548 |
+------------+------------+
```

## store_update_stock

```
+-----------------+------------+---------+--------+
| update_stock_id | bill_date  | bill_no | status |
+-----------------+------------+---------+--------+
|               1 | 2019-09-25 |     123 |      1 |
|               2 | 2019-09-26 |     456 |      1 |
+-----------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

## store_update_stock_details

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------+
| update_stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | status |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------+
|                       1 |               1 |    1 | 900 |      1 |
|                       2 |               2 |    1 | 800 |      1 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+--------+
```

## tbl_fuel

```
+---------+------------+-------------+------+----------+
| fuel_id | vehicle_id | issued_date | item | fuel_qty |
+---------+------------+-------------+------+----------+
|       1 |          2 | 2019-09-25  |    1 |       50 |
|       2 |          2 | 2019-09-25  |    1 |       50 |
|       3 |         18 | 2019-09-26  |    1 |       25 |
|       4 |          2 | 2019-09-27  |    1 |       50 |
+---------+------------+-------------+------+----------+
```

In my model I used the following code :

```
$this->db->select("susd.qty - tf.fuel_qty  as qty");
            $this->db->from('(select susd.item, sum(susd.qty) AS qty
      from store_update_stock_details susd
      join store_update_stock sus on sus.update_stock_id = susd.update_stock_id
      where sus.status = 1
      group by item) susd');
            $this->db->join('(select item, sum(fuel_qty) AS fuel_qty
      from tbl_fuel
      group by item)tf', 'si.item_id=tf.item');
            $this->db->join('store_item si', 'susd.item = si.item_id');
            $this->db->where("sus.status=1");
            $this->db->group_by('si.item_id');
```

And following is the desired output

## Desired Out

```
+------+
| qty  |
+------+
| 1525 |
+------+
```

But anything did not show in the output. I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You might have forgotten to post your existing code.

Comment: @GMB. Added. Pls. see

Comment: Is the goal to add up all the quantities in the store_update_stock_details table, and subtract all the quantities in the tbl_fuel table? It seems like you have a lot of extra stuff going on, if that's the case. What is the actual rule you are trying to express with your code?

Comment: @Jerry. Yes I want to find the balance after all issues. In other words all the quantities in the tbl_fuel table should be deduct from all the quantities in the store_update_stock_details table to find the balance

Comment: Did u solve this?

Comment: Do u need remaining quantity only for diesel?

Comment: @Mohammed. I Solved this. Changed the line $this->db->select("susd.qty - tf.fuel_qty  as qty"); as $this->db->select("(susd.qty) - (tf.fuel_qty)  as qty");